# How do I say "我不是太喜欢旅游." in English?

Tags: translation

The translator gives the translation is

> I don't like traveling very much.

But it sounds like I hate traveling. But I'm just not a traveling enthusiast. If my family need a traveling, I can go with them. I don't initiatively plan to travel.

Comment: Better on https://english.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: 突然发现，大家对“不是太喜欢”这句也有不同看法，有人觉得就是“不喜欢”的委婉说法，有人觉得，还是喜欢，只不过没什么那么喜欢。

Comment: I agree to @Aurus Huang's answer.

Comment: It relies on context to determine the meaning of “不是太喜欢”. “不是太喜欢” usually implies that there is a certain aspect about something which you don't like, but overall it might be ok. E.g. 我不是太喜欢这件衣服， 主要是因为颜色不太好。我不是太喜欢旅游, 因为走路太累。 （意思可能是： 我喜欢看风景，玩啊，什么的， 但是走路太累了，所以总体上说我不是特别喜欢旅游。）

Comment: 突然想起另一个句子“我不是太能吃辣”，这说话“我”还是可以吃辣的，只不过没什么能吃:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a slightly different expression:
I don't like travelling **that** much.

Answer (score 2):

We should not always translate too directly! Leave that to 谷歌！

我不是太喜欢旅游。
I'm a chary cruiser.
I'm not an eager excursionist.
I'm a grudging globe-trotter.
I'm a hesitant hiker.
I'm a reluctant rambler.
I'm a vacillating voyager.
I'm a wavering wanderer.

Answer (score 1):

"我不是太喜欢旅游" does mean you dislike travel

If you don't want to use 'dislike' to describe your feeling on traveling, you can say: "**I am not too keen on traveling**" (我不太热衷于旅行)